# apt-file no longer finds or lists most of the content since Ubuntu 19.10 eoan

Tags: apt, package-management, 19.10, apt-file

**Update 2:** *This seems to be a upstream packaging issue with empty `Contents-amd64.gz` files in the repository. [Therefore I reported a bug in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-file/+bug/1850616).*

I'm a heavy user of `apt-file`. Most of the file I use it to find out about packages I need to install a specific, missing file or vice-versa find out about which package is responsible / owns a specific file.

It seems that since my last update to eoan `apt-file` has completely lost its functionality. It also seems to be a different implementation, because `apt-file update` no longer downloads those `*Contents-amd64.diff.gz`: Instead it does a simple `apt-get update`

```
$ sudo -H apt-file update
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bit-team/testing/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                                      
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                                                      
Hit:5 http://shop.softmaker.com/repo/apt wheezy InRelease                                                                                  
Hit:6 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                                                                              
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marko-preuss/hibiscus/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease                      
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu disco InRelease        
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Also i do no longer get any result at all…

```
$ apt-file search /bin/bash
$ apt-file show bash
```

I know about `dpkg -L <x>`: this i not want I need. I also do not want to leave my terminal and go web surfing.

#### Update

In fact it does return some results but not the complete lists. On running a simple `apt-file search bash` i in fact do get a few rare results from very exotic packages only

```
$ apt-file search bash
code: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/code
code: /usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/emmet/node_modules/dashdash/etc/dashdash.bash_completion.in
…
code: /usr/share/code/resources/completions/bash/code
code-exploration: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/code
code-exploration: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/code-exploration
…
code-insiders: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/code
code-insiders: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/code-insiders
…
linux-tools-common: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/bpftool
```

**Here in contrast the result on a Linux Mint 19.2 equivalent Ubuntu 18.04 installation:**

```
 $ apt-file search /bin/bash
bash: /bin/bash
bash: /usr/bin/bashbug
bash-static: /bin/bash-static
bashburn: /usr/bin/bashburn
pbh5tools: /usr/bin/bash5tools
pbh5tools: /usr/bin/bash5tools.py
```

Comment: `apt-file -v search /bin/bash`  gives maybe a hint what is wrong.

Comment: @nobody Thanks for the tip. This helps, though I don't know how to fix: It misses many `*Contents-amd64.lz` files in direct comparison: https://gist.github.com/bentolor/356ac406b867dffa9ec1d15013f5743b

Comment: Ok: Got it: The upstream files are just empty for eoan: Compare the sizes of the Contents-amd64.gz in http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan/ vs. http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/

Comment: `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` please.

Comment: @nobody Thanks for you support: [The bug now has been fixed upstream](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-file/+bug/1848768)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an [upstream packaging bug and has been fixed within the last hours](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-file/+bug/1848768). A new `apt-file update` and subsequent `apt-file search /bin/bash` now delivers the expected results even under Ubuntu eoan.